# Capturing insert, update and delete events on a table Trigger's and insert into another table

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, plsql, triggers

I have an Activity table which tracks the whole system/solution.
I have created a trigger on Activity table on it. By this trigger I am capturing every single event of the system which will be used by other systems. Further I am inserting the changes(I/U/D) into Event and EVENTCOLVAL table.
EVENTCOLVAL table contains all the column names and corresponding values for the Activity table.

So my trigger looks like this:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIG_Actv
    AFTER INSERT or UPDATE
       ON Activity
       FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
        lvEventId number;
    BEGIN
lvEventId := EventUniqId.NEXTVAL;
    INSERT ALL
          INTO Event (EventId,DateLastMaint)
          VALUES (lvEventId, SYSTIMESTAMP)
          INTO EVENTCOLVAL (EventId, COLNAME, COLVALUE)
          VALUES (lvEventId, 'ActivityCol1', :new.ActivityCol1)
          INTO EVENTCOLVAL (EventId, COLNAME, COLVALUE)
          VALUES (lvEventId, 'ActivityCol2', :new.ActivityCol2)
          INTO EVENTCOLVAL (EventId, COLNAME, COLVALUE)
          VALUES (lvEventId, 'ActivityCol3', :new.ActivityCol3)
          INTO EVENTCOLVAL (EventId, COLNAME, COLVALUE)
          VALUES (lvEventId, 'ActivityCol4', :new.ActivityCol4)
          INTO EVENTCOLVAL (EventId, COLNAME, COLVALUE)
          VALUES (lvEventId, 'ActivityCol5', :new.ActivityCol5)
          INTO EVENTCOLVAL (EventId, COLNAME, COLVALUE)
          VALUES (lvEventId, 'ActivityCol6', :new.ActivityCol6)
          INTO EVENTCOLVAL (EventId, COLNAME, COLVALUE)
          VALUES (lvEventId, 'ActivityCol7', :new.ActivityCol7)
          INTO EVENTCOLVAL (EventId, COLNAME, COLVALUE)
          VALUES (lvEventId, 'ActivityCol8', :new.ActivityCol8)
          ---
          ---
          ---
          ---
          --- 
          INTO EVENTCOLVAL (EventId, COLNAME, COLVALUE)
          VALUES (lvEventId, 'ActivityCol30', :new.ActivityCol30)
          SELECT * FROM dual;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    -------
END TRIG_Actv;
```

P.S : I don't want to use multiple inserts for table EVENTCOLVAL in the trigger, as it will be performance hit because I have 30 columns in Activity table and inserting 31 rows will be a performance issue. Also, metrics for activity table is atleast 100 inserts in 1 second. So, inserting atleast 3000 rows in a second. This will make actvity screen's slower and infact the whole system slower because of the trigger's synchronous nature. Is there any other way possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create nested collection + use compound trigger(Ex. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#CIHEFGFD) + forall insert.
**Pseudocode:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER compound_trigger ...
........
l_nested t_nested := t_nested();
........
BEFORE EACH ROW IS
   BEGIN
    l_nested.extend();
    l_nested(l_nested.count) := ...//populate single row
END BEFORE EACH ROW;

AFTER STATEMENT IS
 BEGIN
    FORALL i IN 1..l_nested.count
     INSERT INTO EVENTCOLVAL(EventId, COLNAME, COLVALUE) VALUES (l_nested(i).eventId, l_nested(i).colName,l_nested(i).value);
 END AFTER STATEMENT;
```

Comment: I am really sorry to comment so late.I understand you said collection, I also understand when you said use FORALL for insert, but didn't understand why you said use compound triggers. Waiting to accept your answer and BTW thanks a lot for the reply :)

Comment: @AnkurBhutani In compound tiggers in before row stmt you add all stmt to collection. Then in after stmt you insert all stmt at once. Imagine this ex: you UPDATE 3 rows in one stmt. Then ordinarly trigger make 3 separate insert and compound recognize that it's one stmt. It fires before each row 3 times, collect data and in after stmt makes one insert of 3 records.

Comment: Sounds interesting, I will give it a go, thanks. Accepting your answer :)